# How to pause the AutoHotKey script when a dropdown list is opened, and resume it after I select the entry of the dropdown list?

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I am working on a data entry project. The software of the company is really peculiar and old-fashioned. I have an AutoHotKey script to copy-paste the entries automatically, but there is a dropdown list that needs to be selected manually (yes, it has to be selected manually) which is stopping me from using the ahk script. Is there any way to automatically pause the script when it encounters the dropdown list, and resumes again when I select the correct entry from the list?

Comment: Not sure, but could you break it into two parts; a key combo to *copy* the list into the clipboard, and a key combo to *paste* it?

Comment: No, the list cannot be copied. I have to select it manually.
Can I at least do this? When the script comes to the dropdown, it waits for me to press a hotkey, when it detects that I have pressed the hotkey, the script continues its job? (and I will select the dropdown entry before pressing the hotkey)

Comment: Waiting can be simple via Msgbox. Please define what is exactly "encounters the dropdown list" and do you know the name of the list control. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc
I am using "tab" to go from one text field to another in the ahk script. So, if the script comes to the point where the dropdown list is, I no longer want the script to press tab, rather wait for me to press (say) f5 key. That's what I meant.

(sorry I am a noob. I have never used ahk and I need to use right away... so not much time to learn... -_-)

Comment: You can use [ControlGetFocus](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/ControlGetFocus.htm) to identify the list control and then use Msgbox to wait for a click on OK.

Comment: What does Window Spy show when the dropdown list is shown and active? To open Window Spy right click the script icon in the system tray and choose Window Spy.